# IupLua - Background de dialog

Tags: lua, iup

Como defino uma imagem como background de um Dialog?
Na documentação diz:

> BACKGROUND (non inheritable): Dialog background color or image. Can be
>   a non inheritable alternative to BGCOLOR or can be the name of an
>   image to be tiled on the background. See also the screenshots of the
>   sample.c results with normal background, changing the dialog
>   BACKGROUND, the dialog BGCOLOR and the children BGCOLOR. (since 3.0)

Ja tentei:

```
require "iuplua"
dlg = iup.dialog{title="test", size="QUARTERxQUARTER", background="back.png"}
dlg:show()

iup.MainLoop()
```

~A imagem está na mesma pasta do programa.~
Mas não acontece nada.
IupLua 3.5.

Comment: Sugiro voce olhar na documentação de como associar uma imagem a um atributo em IUP. O nome do arquivo só funciona em casos bem particulares.

Comment: Não achei nada ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Assim funcionou:

```
require "iuplua"
    require "iupluaim"

    back = iup.LoadImage("back.png")
    dlg = iup.dialog{title="test", size="QUARTERxQUARTER", background=back}

    dlg:show()

    iup.MainLoop()
```